# How to position the untitled section in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

At present if the sortdescriptor is having nil or empty values is being placed in an untitled section which is being placed at the top of the table. I want it to be at the end of the table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is so easy, jst perform a segmentation in which start by the charecter A and check upto z, (or whatever your requiremtn) if it matches nothing, then add it to last array that you are going to show in untititled objects. i have this for contacts. see if it is understandable by u

```
int numContacts=[cList count];

    //NSMutableArray *nonAlphaArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *arrayCollection[27];

    for (int i=0; i<27; i++) {
        arrayCollection[i]=[NSMutableArray array];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<numContacts; i++) 
    {
        Contact *contact= [cList objectAtIndex:i];


        unichar alphaSmall='a';
        unichar alphaBig='A';

        unichar first=0x0000; 
        if([contact.mContactName length]>0)
            first= [contact.mContactName characterAtIndex:0];

        for (int j=0; j<26; ) 
        {

            if (first==alphaSmall || first==alphaBig) 
            {
                [arrayCollection[j] addObject:contact];
                break;
            }

            alphaSmall++;
            alphaBig++;

            j++;

            if (j==26) {
                [arrayCollection[26] addObject:contact];
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<27; i++) 
    {
        [alphaDictionary setObject:arrayCollection[i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm having a SQLite and fetching a list of records. Say for example I've first name, last name and company. I'm creating section based on company. If the company is empty the records were placed on top of the table. I can't use array as I'm dealing with large data. Is it possible to achieve it through sortdescriptor?